# Draw two cards what is the probability the second is higher than the first? Is my approach correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've seen similar questions posted here before but I was wondering if my method/answer was correct

My reasoning was let's say you draw a 2 as your first. Card there are 12 cards with higher values, across 4 suits. Similarly if you draw a 3 there are 11 cards with higher values across 4 suits....son and so forth. So what I did was:

$ \dfrac{4*(12+11+10+......2)}{{52}\choose{2}}$ and I got $\dfrac{4}{17}$ as my answer. I saw a different post on this site where the answer was $\dfrac{8}{17}$ and I was confused what may or may not have missed.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the answer you saw posted?

Answer (score 3):

I assume drawing is done without replacement. The probability that the values are equal is $\frac{3}{51}$. This is because whatever card we draw first, the probability of matching it is $\frac{3}{51}$.

So the probability they are not equal is $\frac{48}{51}$.

Thus by symmetry the probability the second is higher than the first is $\frac{24}{51}$.

**Remark:** Your counting procedure, with slight modification, will work. Note that there are $(52)(51)$ **ordered pairs** of cards.

If the first is $2$, there are $48$ good choices for the second. If the first is $3$, there are $44$, and so on for a total of $4(48+44+\cdots+4)$. Now divide by $(52)(51)$.

Comment: ... and $\frac{24}{51}$ reduces to $\frac{8}{17}$.

Comment: Why would I need to multiply it again by 2 though? Wouldn't 4*(48+44+.......4) imply there are 192 cards that can beat a 2?

Comment: There are $4\cdot 48$ *ordered pairs* of cards the first of which is a $2$ and the second of which beats a $2$.

Comment: I see the 4 comes from the fact that there are 4 of the first card you drew. I thought it was referring to the suits. What if I had done 52 choose 1 instead of 52 choose 2, would that have been correct? I ignored the first card on the numerator because it was a "given" but I didn't adjust accordingly on the denominator I guess?

Comment: Using $\binom{52}{1}$ would give an answer much larger than $1$. An important thing is that numerator and denominator must count the **same sort** of thing, if ordered pairs on top, then ordered pairs at the bottom. There is an alternative way of doing it in your style. If first is $2$ (probability $\frac{4}{52}$), then probability of beating it is $\frac{48}{51}$. If first card is a $3$ (prob. $\frac{4}{52}$) then probability of beating it is $\frac{48}{51}$. And so on. So answer is $\frac{4}{52}\left(\frac{48}{51}+\frac{44}{51}+\cdots\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

Number the cards as so: $1,2,3,...,13$.

If the first card is a $1$, with a $\frac{1}{13}$ chance, then there are 12 numbers that can be higher the second draw, each with four suits:

$$P(card\ 2>1) = \frac{12*4}{51} = \frac{48}{51}$$

If the first card is a $2$, with a $\frac{1}{13}$ chance, then using the same logic it's:

$$P(card\ 2>2) = \frac{11*4}{51} = \frac{44}{51}$$

So we simply want the sum of all these scenarios:

$$P(card\ 2>\ card\ 1) = \frac{1}{13} (P(card\ 2>1) + P(card\ 2>2) + ... + P(card\ 2>13)$$

This sums up to:

$$P(card\ 2>\ card\ 1) =  \frac{1}{13} \sum_{i=1}^{13} \frac{(13-i)*4}{51}$$

It's easy to see that summing up $13-i$ from 1-->13  is the same as summing up $i$ from 12-->0. (plug in for i). We then take out the multiplication. So we are left with:

$$P(card\ 2>\ card\ 1) =  \frac{1}{13} \frac{4}{51} \sum_{i=0}^{12} i $$

$$P(card\ 2>\ card\ 1) =  \frac{1}{13} \frac{4}{51} \sum_{i=1}^{12} i $$

You should also know this neat rule:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

So we have:

$$P(card\ 2>\ card\ 1) =  \frac{1}{13} \frac{4}{51} \frac{12*13}{2} $$

$$P(card\ 2>\ card\ 1) =  \frac{4}{51} \frac{12}{2} $$

$$P(card\ 2>\ card\ 1) =  \frac{2}{51} \frac{12}{1} $$

$$P(card\ 2>\ card\ 1) =  \frac{24}{51} $$